# Distinguish between router reload and "sysUpTime" SNMP counter wrap

Tags: cisco-ios, snmp

If I poll over SNMP for example Cisco IOS interface `ifHCInOctets` counter and last reading is lower than previous reading, then I know that either the device has reloaded, `ifHCInOctets` counter has wrapped, there was an online hardware insertion/removal(OIR) which affected this particular interface or interface was deleted and recreated(this is possible in case of VLAN interface, Port-Channel interface, etc). Now I would like to distinguish between router reload and all those other possibilities for `ifHCInOctets` to start from zero. At first `snmpEngineTime`(range 0 - 2147483647 according to Cisco SNMP object navigator) seemed to be a perfect solution as this counter wraps after 68 years, but it also starts from zero if SNMP agent is restarted, i.e. stopped(`no snmp-server`) and started(`snmp-server community public RO`). This means that one still needs to check `sysUpTime`, which as far as I know, starts from zero **only** in case system is restarted, but unfortunately wraps after every 497 days. This means that simple algorithm seen below would not work if `sysUpTime` wraps between the same checks when `ifHCInOctets` becomes zero:

```
if (( prev_ifHCInOctets > cur_ifHCInOctets )); then
  if (( prev_sysUpTime > cur_sysUpTime )); then
    echo "router reloaded"
  else
    echo "counter wrapped, OIR or interface recreated"
  fi
fi
```

It would be perfection itself if there is a "`sysUpHCTime`" counter, but looks like there is not. What options do I have? I guess one possibility is simply to ignore this highly unlikely situation where both `cur_ifHCInOctets`(current reading of `ifHCInOctets` counter) and `cur_sysUpTime`(current reading of `sysUpTime` counter) are smaller than previous readings because both counters wrapped within the same polling interval. However, just out of interest, what would be the options here? I guess at least one possible option is not to check if `prev_sysUpTime > cur_sysUpTime`, but to check if delta between `prev_sysUpTime` and `cur_sysUpTime` is roughly equivalent to script check interval? I mean for example let's imagine a situation where `prev_sysUpTime` variable was 42949500 and script knows that it got this value 300 seconds ago. Now the `cur_sysUpTime` read by script is 128. As a next step script checks if `cur_sysUpTime`+(42949672-`prev_sysUpTime`) is around 300(for example within range 295 - 305) and if it is, then it is 100% sure that `sysUpTime` started from zero because of counter wrap and not because device reload. 42949672 used in this formula is the maximum value of SNMP `sysUpTime` counter if milliseconds are not included, i.e. maximum value of SNMP `sysUpTime` is 2^32, but last two digits represent milliseconds so for example 4294967296 is 42949672 seconds(about 497 days) and 96 milliseconds.

Sorry for the long post and please let me know if anything is unclear.

Comment: If you are going to trust the hardware data (to the extent that you want to know about reloads) why not ask it to send you coldstart/warmstart traps?

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately this is not an option in this case because devices are not under my management and all I can use are SNMP GET requests. In addition, downside of SNMP traps is more complicated script as it needs to run as daemon and listen for SNMP traps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would approach it this way: fetch sysuptime, then calculate the boot date/time and the predicted next wrap date/time. Write both to the log. Calculate the next poll time and if it is after the predicted next wrap date/time by a little margin, write a 'wrap expected' bit to the log.  Next time you fetch, look at the 'wrap expected' bit and the predicted next wrap time from the log, and if the bit is 1 and if the predicted wrap time and current boot times are pretty close (extremely close if your server and router are both using NTP) then you know it has wrapped and not rebooted.  If not, you know it rebooted.  If the wrap expected bit wasn't set, simply go back to the main script logic and calculate the new boot time and predicted wrap time, make your wrap prediction bit, and write it all to the log.

You are trying to guard against a reboot false positive by not anticipating the uptime wrap, AND a reboot true negative by assuming the counter wrapped when it actually rebooted.  To do both you need pretty careful timing, and even then it just reduces the probability (down past 1 in 1,000,000), but it doesn't eliminate them.

If you want to go full tilt, you can do something like adding a second detection layer on top.  For example look at the UDP traffic counter: since you are polling via snmp you will be constantly incrementing it a tiny bit.  Since there probably arent many other SNMP polls taking place, it will not likely wrap very often (if at all compared to reboots for other reasons) so if you looked at sysuptime going down AND udp traffic count going down you can increase the confidence that you caught a reboot.

Comment: As I understand your approach, the "wrapped" bit is stored in order to detect this particular polling interval when `sysUpTime` is expected to wrap? In addition, please explain the "if the predicted reboot time and current boot times are pretty close then you know it(`sysUpTime`) has wrapped" part. I mean what is this predicted reboot time? And by current boot time you mean the device boot date/time calculated earlier, e.g. `device_uptime=$(snmpget -Ov -v 2c -c public device sysUpTime.0 | gsed -r 's/^.*\((.*)\).*$/\1/;s/.{2}$//'); cur_time=$(date +%s); boot_time=$((cur_time - device_uptime))`?

Comment: My wording was inelegant, I fixed it to hopefully make more sense.  Using the wrap prediction bit is probably unnecessary since if you have the next wrap prediction time in the log anyway you might as well just compare it to the current boot calculation.  And yes, the boot time would be the date/time of the system boot as suggested by sysuptime (either the actual boot time or the time that sysuptime wrapped to 0).

Comment: I don't see a connection between predicted `sysUpTime` counter wrap time and current system boot time. For example let's say that `(( wrap_expected_bit == 1 ))` test is true and thus script checks if predicted wrap time is let's say +/-5 seconds from system boot time: `(( next_wrap_time >= (boot_time-5) && next_wrap_time <= (boot_time+5) ))`. Router is not reloaded after setting the `wrap_expected_bit` to 1 and has uptime 5057293. `boot_time` variable has value 1429560604(cur_time - device_uptime) and `next_wrap_time` would be 1472510276. `next_wrap_time` is always system boot time + 42949672.

Comment: Making the connection is where storing the prediction for the next check is necessary. If you record the predicted wrap time (sysuptime_max-sysuptime)+now as a date, which for example evaluates "9:50:10AM June 20 2015", and then read this in on the next run.  So, when you run next and read the prediction in, read the sysuptime, and you compare those two.  You will take the evaulated boot time (now-sysuptime) so for example "9:50:09AM June 20 2015" and compare it to what you logged on the last run, and see that they are close enough to say with reasonable certainty that the counter wrapped.

Comment: I understand now, thanks! However, do you see that this approach has any advantages over checking if delta between `cur_sysUpTime`(current reading of `sysUpTime`) and `prev_sysUpTime`(previous reading of `sysUpTime` counter) is roughly equivalent to script check interval? I mean: `if (( prev_ifHCInOctets > cur_ifHCInOctets )); then if (( (cur_sysUpTime-prev_sysUpTime) >= (polling_interval-5) && (cur_sysUpTime-prev_sysUpTime) <= (polling_interval+5) )); then echo "counter wrapped, OIR or interface recreated"; else echo "router reloaded"; fi; fi` IMHO both solutions would be equally reliable..

Comment: Yes, that is a good way of reducing the formula to its most essential elements.  I usually lean toward converting to human-readable formats early on to help with debugging and operation, since the computer is more than powerful enough to do a few extra things to make it easy on us.

Answer (score 2):

What you want is the SNMP equiv of: `System restarted at 15:12:52 EDT Wed Jun 3 2015` from `show hardware`. However, I am unaware of any MIB exporting that.

Another option would be tracking the syslog message counts. I don't know which routers actually support that; my 3745 running 12.4T doesn't.

Comment: Yes, timestamp of last boot would be perfect, but as much as I searched, there is no such SNMP object. However, what's your opinion on not to check if `prev_sysUpTime > cur_sysUpTime`, but to check if delta between `prev_sysUpTime` and `cur_sysUpTime` is roughly equivalent to script check interval? Do you see any problems with this?